# How do planes on taxiway get back to terminal after an accident?

Tags: accidents, ground-operations, taxiing

When there is accident that blocks the runway, how do other planes that are on taxiways or holding points move back to terminal? After all, the runway is closed due to the accident and planes cannot just reverse back to gate.

Answer (score 7):

A runway may be technically closed, but in an emergency some of it may still be passable for taxi traffic under ATC control.

For example at Haneda:

[image]
<sup>Source:[Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:AGC_TOKYO-HANEDA_HND_RJTT.gif)</sup>

Runway 34R/16L at Haneda has two parallel taxiways. Any aircraft on those taxiways can simply taxi ahead to a turning point and follow ground control directions to a gate.

After the accident Runway 34R was technically closed, but any aircraft holding for take off near the threshold could taxi onto the runway, proceed to the next exit point, and exit the runway again, all under ATC control, obviously.

If that's not possible then they could enter the runway, backtrack and exit at the next entry point.

For any aircraft for which these options are not feasible, they can sit tight and await the services of a tug.